# Migrating assets from Cloudinary to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudinary

I have files on Cloudinary and I want to move them to AWS.
How can I migrate these assets on Cloudinary to AWS?

Comment: Please don't scream

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [get resources](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources) method from Cloudinary's Admin API to list the resources in your account. In the response, you'll get the URL to each asset. You can then use cURL or any HTTP client library to grab the contents of each file and store them locally, upload to S3 or use them in any other way as required.